# How is data stored in a database?

Tags: database

In my course we've learnt about different database models - how data is stored theoretically with trees, etc. 
my question is more practical: I want to know how the data is stored into the storage. Are there algorithms that distribute the data to the 'hard drive'? 
So in big databases is the data spread randomly to the storage or will the drives be filled like step-by-step until they're full, before the next one gets data to save?

Comment: This is far too broad of a question to be answered practically within content guidelines of this site.  The answer very much depends on the specific implementations of the database engine, the underlying operating system and even the file system.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that. Can you recommend any websites or literature where I can get knowledge about that? I don't think my course will consider those parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing data in a database is not a major problem. Instead, the problems lies in viewing or manipulating the stored data. For example how frequently one wants to access the data, when do you want to access data, which data you want to access etc. questions to be answered. If you are sure about your data manipulation detail, then you can design tables accordingly and choose appropriate techniques to manipulate the data.
You can refer any books on database management systems.

[Advanced DBMS Tutorials](http://www.exploredatabase.com)